# C# string interpolation throws IOException

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

I have a weird issue and am wondering if anyone else has come across this before. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong and someone can point out what I am doing wrong.

The issue is, I am creating a zip file and adding a bunch of files into it. I am wrapping the zip creation in a `using`, which should properly close the zip file after it finished adding files to it. The weird part is, when I use a regular string for the file's path, everything works fine. When I use string interpolation to create the path, instead of a regular string, it throws an IOException "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

Here's the code:

```
try
{
    string sourceDirectory = @"c:\path\to\files\that\need\zipping";
    string destinationDirectory = @"c:\path\to\zip\file";
    string zipFilename = "someFilename.zip";
    string filename = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", destinationDirectory, zipFilename);
    //string filename = $@"{destinationDirectory}\{zipFilename}";
    using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(filename, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (string pathToFile in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory))
        {
            zip.CreateEntryFromFile(pathToFile, Path.GetFileName(pathToFile));
        }
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // Lands here when using string interpolation.
}
```

The code above works and does not throw an IOException. However, when I comment out the `string.Format()` line uncomment the `$@"{destinationDirectory}\{zipFilename}"` line, it then throws the IOException.

Any thoughts as to why it would do that? Is the string interpolation somehow holding a handle on the file and not releasing it?

Comment: You need `@` before both your paths.

Comment: Sorry. Those are there, just weren't included in this post. I have updated it.

Comment: This is compiled to [exactly the same code](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3YoATpFiDUKSFWRg+EACJg5qUsj5yEMALwwAAgCJSALgA6udQAsHRhwC8wuBwDMwIlRrHHYYeUUYb1wAMUDUCCp0VHMYaxA+ZLigxOSAOmiQmTYI6BgAnKSUi1KoPJjjdHUxGyYABgBfByYARg7rABoYZVVEjS1dfUNjBCHo7ISqiVDZZAUyisXkgCZUgBJWkY0xzR09AyMTLqZ5+NzUfpW2DuwOoAA==). Are you sure that's what throws?

Comment: @i3arnon: Yes, I have tried it three more times to be certain. I am starting to wonder if it has something to do with the ZipFile.Open() method? Perhaps that method is having difficulties with the string?

Comment: I think the exception is clear: IOException "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". A malformed string would not cause it to be used by another process.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: I get that, what I'm wondering is, why it would happen based on how the string is formatted? Why would using string.Format() work, but string interpolation cause it to fail?

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint after the `filename` creation, and inspect it, in both cases. If the generated string is the same, then your issue is not with string interpolation at all. If it's not the same, either you wrote it wrong, or there's a bug in the C# compiler.

Answer (score 4):

String interpolation cannot throw an `IOException`. The exception is probably thrown by the following line: `using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(filename, ZipArchiveMode.Create))`.

You could test the program with and without string interpolation on differently named files to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect there is something else which is causing IOException.
I tired running your code in both scenario you have mentioned ,its works good.